# What happens when you dereference a postincrement C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, operator-precedence

I am receiving a lot of conflicting answers about this. But as I always understood it.

When we have a pointer in C and use it in a post increment statement, the post increment will always happen after the line of code resolves.

```
int array[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
int* p = array;
printf("%d", *p++); // This will output 0 then increment pointer to 1
```

output :

```
0
```

Very simple stuff. Now here's where I am receiving a bit of dissonance in the information people are telling me and my own experience.

```
// Same code as Before
int array[0] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
int* p = array;
printf("%d", *(p++)); // Issue with this line
```

output :

```
0
```

Now when I run that second version of the code The result is that it will output 0 THEN increments the pointer. The order of operations implied by the parentheses seems to be violated. However some other answers on this site tell me that the proper thing that should happen is that the increment should happen before the dereference. So I guess my question is this: Is my understanding correct? Do post increment statements always execute at the end of the line?

Additional Info:

I am compiling with gcc on linux mint with gcc version ubuntu 4.8.4

I have also tested this on gcc on debian with version debian 4.7.2

Comment: _The order of operations implied by the bracket_ - `(` and `)` are parenthesis, not brackets. I assume that is what you're referring to from the context. Proper terminology is essential in order to communicate well.

Comment: Is this actually compiling without errors? Your array initialization is incorrect and your comment slashes are wrong.

Comment: I have made the obvious corrections to the post. Should I have also fixed the array declaration?

Comment: `i = *p++` is equivalent to `i = *p++` and is equivalent to `(i = *p, p = p + 1, i)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP's "The result is that it will output 0 THEN increments the pointer." is not correct.

The postfix increment returns the value of the pointer.  Consider this value as a copy of the original pointer's value.  The pointer is incremented which does not affect the copy.

> The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented. ... C11dr 6.5.2.4 2

Then the copy of the pointer is de-referenced and returns the `0`.  That is the *functional* sequence of events.

Since the side-effect of incrementing the pointer and de-referencing that copy of the pointer do not effect each other, which one occurs first is irrelevant.  The compiler may optimized as it likes.

"the end of the line" is not involved in code.  It is the end of the expression that is important.

Comment: *It is the end of the expression that is important*... not exactly for this discussion, the sequence points are what matters.

Comment: damn, excellent answer that makes so much sense now. So the ++ operator actually returns the value of the operand. But the value of the operand is actually incremented. 

So if that's the case would that mean a comparison like this would always be false?

    if(i++ == 1 && i == 1 );

but

   if( i == 1 && i++ == 1);

could return true?

Comment: @user2601592 Agree in both cases.  Yet code is on thin ice.  Manipulating `i` on various sides of `&&` and `||` are easy to code in a way not intended.  Remember that if the code is hard to understand, it is hard to maintain and someone after you (of lesser ability) may _fix_ it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning between `*p++` and `*(p++)`.

This is because postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary operators.

Both these expressions mean "`p` is incremented, and its previous value is dereferenced".

If you want to increment the object being referenced by the pointer, then you need to override precedence by writing `(*p)++`.

**No version of your code can produce output and *then* increment `p`. The reason is that `p` is incremented in an *argument expression* which produces a value that is passed into `printf`. In C, a sequence point occurs just before a function is called. So the new value of `p` must settle in place before `printf` executes. And the output cannot take place until `printf` is called.**

Now, you have to take the above with a slight grain of salt. Since `p` is a local variable, modifying it isn't an externally visible effect. If the new value of `p` isn't used anywhere, the increment can be entirely optimized away. But suppose we had an `int * volatile p;` at file scope, and used that instead. Then the expression `printf("...", *p++)` has to increment `p` before `printf` is called.

Comment: A postfix increment is a unary operator

Comment: @nicomp Indeed, in computer science that is true and it's good that you paid attention in school. However, in ISO C terminology, we have "unary expressions" and "postfix expressions".  See C99 6.5.2 "Postfix operators" and 6.5.3 "Unary expressions".  On significant meaning of "unary operator" in C is that it's one of the operators possible in a unary expression, playing the role described in that piece of grammar (where it appears on the left).

Comment: thank you for the validation. From now on I will speak only in ISO C terminology.

Comment: @nincomp That is not necessary; my point is only that I'm not incorrect. I'm just used to discussing the C grammar using the (sometimes peculiar) vocabulary that surrounds its definition.

Comment: So is a postfix increment a unary operator or not?

Comment: @nicomp - In the context of C, *unary* and *postfix* refer to specific levels of precedence, not number of operands.  Yes, colloquially, we'd refer to a postfix `++` as a unary operator (only takes one operand).  In the context of C, though, we would *not* call it a unary operator, because in C all unary operators are prefix (address-of `&`, dereference `*`, prefix `++` and `--`, `sizeof`, etc.).  Note that some postfix operators take multiple operands (subscript `[]`, function call `()`, member selection `.` and `->`).  Again, this is about precedence, not number of operands.

Comment: @John Bode C11 **6.5.3 Unary operators** lists _unary-expression_ and _unary-operator_.  The first includes _postfix-expressions_ as used in `p++` and the second includes `- * &` and others.  It seems reasonable and C-ish to call `++` a _Unary operator_ as it is listed under the spec's section of that name.

Comment: @chux Comma is the "comma operator". Yet, not here: `enum color { color_red, color_black }`. *That* comma cannot be correctly called a comma operator.  The derivation goes only one way. If we have a grammar element *unary-operator*, of course it can derive `++`. That doesn't make the `++` token a unary operator independent of context such that we can point to any `++` anywhere and call it that.

Comment: @Kaz Thanks for your detailed insight.  The C spec lists postfix `++` and prefix `++` under "Unary operators".  Unlike `,` with `++`, there is no other context.  That makes it reasonable in C discourse to identity `++` as a unary operator in all contexts.  The spec refers to _postfix ++ operator_ - which is what I would call it. Someone classifying `++` a unary operator does not go against the C spec even though both `++` do not live in the _unary-operator_, but the _unary-expression_ grammar element.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `p++` has a *result* (the value of `p` before the increment) and a *side effect* (the value of `p` is updated to point to the next object of type `int`).

Postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*p++` is already parsed as `*(p++)`; you will see no difference in behavior between those two forms.  IOW, the dereference operator is applied to the *result* of `p++`; the line

```
printf("%d", *p++);
```

is *roughly* equivalent to

```
printf("%d", *p);
p++;
```

with the caveat that `p` will actually be updated before the call to `printf`<sup>1</sup>.

However, `(*p)++` *will* be different; instead of incrementing the pointer, you are incrementing the thing `p` *points to*.

---

<sup>1.  The side effect of a `++` or `--` operator must be applied before the next *sequence point*, which in this particular case occurs between the time the function arguments are evaluated and the function itself is called.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this. Let's ignore the printf function altogether and make things simpler.

If we said

```
int i;
int p=0;
i = p++;
```

Then i would be equal to zero because p was equal to zero but now p has been incremented by one; so now i still equals zero and p is equal to 1.

Ignoring the declarations of i and p as integers, if we wrap this as in the example, `i = *(p++)`, then the same action occurs but i now contains the value pointed at by p which had the value of zero. However, the value of p, now, has been incremented by one.

Comment: Your explanation adds confusion by mixing `int` and `int*` types for `p`.  Why not just say that `i = *(p++)` is equivalent to `(i = *p, p = p + 1, i)`

Comment: @chqrlie Every explanation should be as simple as possible.

Comment: indeed! mine fits in a 1 line comment `;-)`